# Improve scala algorithm in a play template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'd like to improve an algorithm in a play template:

linklist.scala.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            @for((l,i) <- linkList.zipWithIndex) {
                @if((i/2)*2==i) { 
                    @* even index *@
                    @components.link(l)
                }
            }
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            @for((l,i) <- linkList.zipWithIndex) {
                @if((i/2)*2!=i) { 
                    @* ood index *@
                    @components.link(l)
                }
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

link.scala.html

```
@(link: Link) 
<tr>
    <td><a href="@link.uri.toString()" class="btn btn-primary">@link.uri.getHost()@link.uri.getPath()</a>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>@link.description</td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to have just one `<div class="span6">` in the linklist.scala.html. The only difference is the if statement, I divide the linklist in two parts (with odd and even index numbers). Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'improve'? Do you just want an `else` statement next to the `if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the exact syntax but I think this approach should give you the markup you're looking for:

```
<div class="row">
  @for(remainder <- List(0,1)) {
    <div class="span6">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        @for((l,i) <- linkList.zipWithIndex) {
          @if(i%2 == remainder) { 
            @components.link(l)
          }
        }
      </table>
    </div>
  }
</div>
```